# How to compare a string value in an IF else condition using shell script

Tags: sh

#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 2 ]
then
echo "Usage $0 servername envtype"
exit 1
fi

servername=$1
envtype=$2
srv=`echo $servername | tr "a-z" "A-Z"`
srvtype=`echo $envtype | tr "a-z" "A-Z"`
echo $srv
echo $srvtype

if [ "${srv}" <> "SCP" ];
then
if [" ${srv}" <> "RENTD" ];
then
echo "Invalid servername"
exit 1;
fi
fi

I am getting this error when running the shell script

- [ 2 -lt 2 ]
- servername=scp
- envtype=prd
- echo scp
- tr a-z A-Z
- srv=SCP
- echo prd
- tr a-z A-Z
- srvtype=PRD
- echo SCP
  SCP
- echo PRD
  PRD
- [ SCP ]
- [ SCP ]
  /tmp/testupper.sh: 19: [ SCP: not found

Comment: Glad you found your issue.  Your question formatting doesn't reflect what is code as opposed to text (eg, your actual "I am getting this error..."   Could you `Edit` your question (from the `Share` `Edit` `Follow` `Flag` set of links?  In edit mode, highlight the code and click the `{ }` button to format it.  (Really, all that does is put 4 spaces in front of each line of code, but that's all markdown needs.)  See also https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for other available formatting in questions and answers.  And, even though you found your answer, it's still worth editing for posterity

Answer (score 1):

Found my issue.

```
[" ${srv}" <> "RENTD" ]
```

there is a space being prefixed to the `srv` variable, between the `"` and the `$`: `" ${srv}"`

Comment: Right - spaces are usually not syntactical in `sh` (ie, POSIX family) shells, but inside quoted strings they are always literal characters.

Comment: Also - make sure you know what `sh`-shell you are really using.  One way is with this oneliner:  `which sh | xargs ls -la` .  That should show you where the symlink `sh` is really pointing.

Comment: You may accept your own answer to indicate that your issue has been resolved.